# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular 7 and I need to post a request to the server. Data collected by the Angular reactive form. This is the original structure that needs to achieve.

```
{
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "user": {
        "id" : 7
    },
    "category": {
        "id" : 2
    },
    "description" : "test description",
    "quantity" : 2
    
}
```

And this is the model class.

```
export class SampleRequest {
  title: string;
  category: { id: number};
  user: { id: number};
  description: string;
  quantity: number;
}
```

Then I suggest assigning elements one by one to the SampleRequest object. Because cannot add user Id and category Id directly. If it is wrong, Please mention.

And this is the sample-request.ts class.

```
  requestForm: FormGroup;
  sampleRequest: SampleRequest = new SampleRequest();
  isSuccessful = false;
  isFailed = false;
  isProgress = false;
  errMsg: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.requestForm = this.fb.group({
      title : ['', Validators.required],
      category : ['',Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern]]
    });

  }



  onSubmit() {
    this.sampleRequest.title = this.requestForm.get('title').value;
    this.sampleRequest.category.id = this.requestForm.get('category').value; //here is the problem
    this.sampleRequest.user.id = this.tokenStorage.getUser().id;  //and here
    this.sampleRequest.description = this.requestForm.get('description').value;
    this.sampleRequest.quantity = this.requestForm.get('quantity').value;
    console.log(this.sampleRequest);
    this.userService.newSampleRequest(this.sampleRequest)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.isSuccessful = true;
          this.isProgress = true;
        },
        error => {
          this.isFailed = true;
          this.isProgress = true;
          this.errMsg = error.error.message;
        }
      );
  }

}
```

Then I got the error TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined. User Id is assigned by the logged-in user Id through JWT token. Category Id is assigned by the reactive form.

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking but the JSON data you've pasted slightly differs from the TS interface you've defined - `user.id` is a number in your JSON while you've defined it as a string in the interface and `quantity` is a string in your JSON while you've defined it as a number in the interface.

Comment: You should probably also include the contents of your `TokenStorageService` class.

Comment: @Edric it was a mistake. But that's not the, I changed it to the number but still have the problem.

Comment: @Edric TokenStorageService simply returns the user id like 7 (As a number without quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, even though you have given

```
sampleRequest: SampleRequest = new SampleRequest();
```

the other components- user and category inside the sampleRequest object will still be undefined.

Try creating a new empty category and new empty user object and set that to the sampleRequest object

```
sampleRequest.category = {};
sampleRequest.user = {};
```

and that "TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined" error should not come up anymore.